# replacing string from '\' into '/' Python

Tags: python

I've been strugling with some code where i need to change simple `\` into `/` in Python. Its a path of file- Python doesn't read path of file in Windows'es way, so i simply want to change Windows path for Python to read file correctly.

I want to parse some text from game to count statistics. Im Doing it this way:

```
import re

pathNumbers = "D:\Gry\Tibia\packages\TibiaExternal\log\test server.txt"
pathNumbers = re.sub(r"\\", r"/",pathNumbers)

fileNumbers = open (pathNumbers, "r")

print(fileNumbers.readline())
fileNumbers.close()
```

But the Error i get back is

`----> 6 fileNumbers = open (pathNumbers, "r") OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:/Gry/Tibia/packages/TibiaExternal\test server.txt'`

And the problem is, that function `re.sub()` and `.replace()`, give the same result- almost full path is replaced, but last char to change always stays untouched.

Do you have any solution for this, because it seems like changing those chars are for python a sensitive point.

Comment: Your `pathNumbers` string has the escape sequence `\t` in it, which is a tab character, not a backslash. The rest of the code doesn't replace it because the string literally doesn't have a backslash there; it has a tab character. Try writing `pathNumbers = r"..."` with the `r` so that backslashes aren't escape sequences.

Comment: @kaya3 YES! That Works! And wow... I havent even suspect that `\t` going to be read this way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer:**

If you want to use paths on different plattforms join them with

```py
os.path.join(path,*paths)
```

This way you don't have to work with the different separators at all.

---

**Answer to what you intended to do**:

The actual problem is, that your `pathNumbers` variable is not raw (leading `r` in definition), meaning that the backslashes are used as escape characters. In most cases this does not change anything, because the combinations with the following characters don't have a meaning. `\t` is the *tab* character, `\n` would be the *newline* character, so these are not simple backslash characters any more.

So simply write

```py
pathNumbers = r"D:\Gry\Tibia\packages\TibiaExternal\log\test server.txt"
```